# What are windows 7 online ID providers?

Tags: windows-7

What are windows 7 online ID providers and what is their use?

I see that at this time only provider is Windows Live. I also heard that it has something to do with OpenID, but I wasn't able to obtain clear information about that.

Comment: @CloseVoter: Any comment why? I didn't think this would be appropriate for web-apps site because you actually install software on your computer when you use that. It also seems to be related to usernames and LAN file sharing, so I'd say it's a good fit for this site.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Don't you sign all the StackExchange websites using your OpenID?

Comment: @jason404 I think that you do. What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Just meant that it was the same thing. I use MyOpenID, FacebookID and GoogleID, as well as LiveID. Once the other providers are added to Windows single sign-in, there would only be rare instances where you'd need to give a password.  If only phpBB and the other old style forums got into using OpenID as well.

Comment: @jason404  OK. What actually bothers me about this whole feature set is that it seems abandoned. I have a feeling that it's been quite some time since that option has been enabled and still Windows Live is only provider available. Also, there is option to register and use smart cards with Windows Live ID Sign In and it leads to a website which reports error 500. It used to work back in beta days, from what I could find out. I'm afraid that this whole idea will end up same as Vista Ultimate Extras.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: It may have been forgotten about, but the Live team have been extremely busy recently. With the Live web services now radically improved, maybe they would promote their own LiveID, as opposed to Facebook's and Google's. In any case, all these other OpenID providers always stay signed in for me anyway, and the ones that keep on asking for passwords (YahooID in particular) get signed in automatically on my laptop (through the nifty ThinkVantage Password Manager with fingerprint reader), so I'm not too bothered.

Answer (score 5):

Information extracted from this tutorial on a totally different subject:
[Streaming Your Windows Media Player 12 Library Over the Internet](http://www.7tutorials.com/streaming-your-windows-media-player-12-library-over-internet)

> The online ID provider software simply
>   lets you link one of your online
>   accounts (such as the one you use for
>   email and instant messaging) to your
>   Windows 7 user accounts. For now, you
>   can only link your Windows Live
>   account, but there are plans to roll
>   out other online ID providers (such as
>   Google, OpenID or Facebook).

*Later update:* I recently published a tutorial which explains everything there is to know about Windows Live ID, including the services and apps that use it. You can find it here:

[Simple Questions: What is Windows Live ID?](http://www.7tutorials.com/simple-questions-what-windows-live-id)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: That guide looks really interesting. I wonder why these options aren't advertised enough....

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Windows Live Mesh (which is a part of Windows Live 2011 package) also uses Windows Live Online ID provider in order to synchronise directories and settings over Internett across different computers.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be speaking to the future of the Windows 7 online ID providers from the point-of-view of how Microsoft is going to be using it. Even Windows Essential 2012, which includes the Windows LiveID Online ID Provider, will be supported only through 2017-01-10. support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17779/download-windows-essentials

*Sorry, can't make it my third link without more rep. Please copy and paste it.*

Might still be downloadable and usable from some of the older packages, but I'm not willing to risk my current/legacy Windows 7 setup at the moment to test this. Their version numbers and release dates are very old: minimum 5 years old.

Here are the links:

2011-06-29 - 15.4.3538.0513 - [Windows Live Sign-in Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26686)

2009-10-01 - 6.5 - [Windows Live ID Sign-in Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15106)